# React table not rendering data returned from an API unless I create dummy data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I have a basic React Table that's not rendering data when I build the object array from data returned by an API.

I'm refactoring the data from the API into it's own object, pushing the objects to an array, and then setting it to state (using useState), which the table should then render.

```
            let tableData = []
            pendingKYC.forEach(async (address) => {
                let userData = await contract.retrieveOwnerInfo(address);
                let refactored = {
                    address: address,
                    firstName: userData.firstName,
                    lastName: userData.lastName,
                }
                tableData.push(refactored);
            });
           setPendingKYCRequestsTableData(tableData);
```

However it's not rendering. Headers only, the rest is blank. I discovered that if I create a "dummy" array of objects containing the exact same data, and pushing *that* to the state instead, it works fine.

```
const testData = [{
                address: "0x8e5acD67EFDdB1fb8c54491C8A0EB6f3CFD77ae3",
                firstName: "Killua",
                lastName: "Zoldyck",
            },
            {
                address: "0x2b71400D0Eb16b0C878aa12d4cF9FbE03fFcF36f",
                firstName: "Gon",
                lastName: "Freecs",
            }];

            setPendingKYCRequestsTableData(testData);
```

Using console.logs all over the place and inspecting it in the Chrome console, the only difference I can see is that it appears to be in a different format.
[image: console screenshot]

The one that doesn't work (the first one) is a [] type of array.
The one that does work (my dummy data) is a [{...}, {...}] type of array.

What the heck is the difference? Can someone shed some light on what I might be doing wrong?

Not to do a code-dump but here is my Table component

```
const PendingKYCTable = ({pendingKYCRequestsTableData, approveButtonHandler}) =>{
 

    
   useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("PendingKYCTable parent component useEffect", pendingKYCRequestsTableData);
   });

    console.log("PendingKYCTable rendered", pendingKYCRequestsTableData);

    const columns = React.useMemo(
        () => [
        {
          Header: "Pending KYC Requests",
          columns: [
            {
                Header: "Address",
                accessor: "address"
            },
            {
                Header: "First Name",
                accessor: "firstName"
            },
            {
                Header: "Last Name",
                accessor: "lastName"
            },
           
          ]
        }
      ]);

      const Table = ({ columns, data }) => {
        const {
          getTableProps,
          getTableBodyProps,
          headerGroups,
          rows,
          prepareRow
        } = useTable({
          columns,
          data
        });
        console.log("Table component data var", data);
        useEffect (() => {
            console.log("Table useEffect",data);
        });
      
        return (
          <table {...getTableProps()}>
            <thead>
              {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
                <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                  {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                    <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render("Header")}</th>
                  ))}
                </tr>
              ))}
            </thead>
            <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
              {rows.map((row, i) => {
                prepareRow(row);
                return (
                  <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                    {row.cells.map(cell => {
                      return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>;
                    })}
                  </tr>
                );
              })}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        );
      };

      return(
        <div>{pendingKYCRequestsTableData && <Table columns={columns} data={pendingKYCRequestsTableData} getTrProps={approveButtonHandler}/>}</div>

    );
};

export default PendingKYCTable;
```

and I'm invoking it from the parent component, passing in the state containing the data like this:

```
<div><PendingKYCTable pendingKYCRequestsTableData={pendingKYCRequestsTableData} approveButtonHandler={approveButtonHandler}/></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some advice elsewhere that was very helpful so I'm showing how it was resolved. Apparently you can't use a forEach loop with async requests. A regular for loop works just fine. I replaced my forEach loop with this:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < pendingKYC.length; i++){
        const address = pendingKYC[i];
        let userData = await contract.retrieveOwnerInfo(address);
        let refactored = {
            address: address,
            firstName: userData.firstName,
            lastName: userData.lastName,
        }
        tableData.push(refactored);
    }
```